# Should we extend version tags ban?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

We had banned `wordress-[version]` tags, but had cautiously left possibility of `[version]` tags for cases where they are really required.

I was not keeping an eye on those and it seems we just got a resurgence of meaningless version tags, mostly on questions that don't need them.

I propose we get version tags banned in all forms. If some question is really that specific to version then it could just as well be mentioned and stressed in question body. Version tags just get improperly used in bulk and pollute site with meaningless meta information instead.

Comment: +1 and double that.

Comment: Since we help people with general questions usually by looking at the latest version of WordPress anyway, I don't think this would come back to haunt us so I personally at least would not mind if all version tags, both wordpress-[version] and [version] are gone.

Comment: I agree. The philosophy of WordPress is continual updates. Old major releases are not formally/officially supported as "legacy" branches. Thus, it would be counter-intuitive to provide support-by-proxy for questions that are only relevant to old versions of WordPress. And for questions that apply to the current WordPress version, adding the version tag is superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

+1 to banning version tags outright.

One potential way to identify questions as specific to a given version of WordPress - assuming said version is older than the current version - would be for questions to be closed, with the closing explanation indicating that the question is specific to WordPress version X.Y.